# Prevent SparkHistoryServer from redirecting to HTTP

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, amazon-elb

Right now I have an ELB interfacing between all of my Spark services and public traffic.  When I attempt to see job history details on the Spark History Server, it ends up rerouting to http, ignoring that it is behind https, and then the destination is unreachable.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have `spark.ssl.historyServer.enabled=true` set in your SHS config?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56412083/spark-history-server-behind-load-balancer-is-redirecting-to-http)  You are free to edit your question and improve it.

Comment: @mazaneicha - yep.  Turns out it's just best not to use ELB :)